# Create new variables with lag data from all current variables

Tags: r, variables, dplyr, lag

My dataset has about 20 columns and I would like to create 7 new columns with lagged data for each of the 20 current columns.

For example I have column x, y, and z. I would like to create a columns for xlag1, xlag2, xlag3, xlag4, xlag5, xlag6, xlag7, ylag1, ylag2, etc..

My current attempt is with dplyr in R -

```
aq %>% mutate(., 
          xlag1 = lag(x, 1),
          xlag2 = lag(x, 2),
          xlag3 = lag(x, 3),
          xlag4 = lag(x, 4),
          xlag5 = lag(x, 5),
          xlag6 = lag(x, 6),
          xlag7 = lag(x, 7),
          )
```

As you can see it'll take alot of lines of codes to cover all 20 columns. Is there a more efficient way of doing this ? If possible in dplyr and R as I'm most familiar with the package.

Comment: My apologies! you're definitely correct! I'll correct it

Comment: No problem, please check the solution below, it is easier to do this in `data.table`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  The `shift` from data.table can take a sequence of 'n'.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(aq)[, paste0('xlag', 1:7) := shift(x, 1:7)]
```

If there are multiple columns,

```
setDT(aq)[, paste0(rep(c("xlag", "ylag"), each = 7), 1:7) := 
                 c(shift(x, 1:7), shift(y, 1:7))]
```

If we have many columns, then specify the columns in `.SDcols` and loop through the dataset, get the `shift`, `unlist` and assign to new columns

```
setDT(aq)[, paste0(rep(c("xlag", "ylag"), each = 7), 1:7) := 
   unlist(lapply(.SD, shift, n = 1:7), recursive = FALSE) , .SDcols = x:y]
```

---

We can also use the `shift` in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
aq %>% 
    do(setNames(data.frame(., shift(.$x, 1:7)), c(names(aq), paste0('xlag', 1:7))))
```

and for multiple columns

```
aq %>%
  do(setNames(data.frame(., shift(.$x, 1:7), shift(.$y, 1:7)), 
         c(names(aq), paste0(rep(c("xlag", "ylag"), each = 7), 1:7) )))
```

#### data

```
aq <- data.frame(x = 1:20, y  = 21:40)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked! I need to read up on working with data.table.